# Remote desktop on Windows Server 2008 R2 shows keyboard layout from connecting computer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, keyboard, language

I have a german Windows 2008 R2  with English Multilanguage Pack installed. It has only german, english keyboard defined. It works fine.

I use Windows 7 with PL version and PL keyboard settings. And my customer who logs in to that Windows 2008 R2 uses german Windows 7, Windows XP.

When I login to Windows 2008 R2 it automatically switches keyboard on server to PL (and I can choose between 3 keyboard, however there's no way to remove that PL keyboard).  This wouldn't be a big problem but my customer using german windows also see this PL keyboard and it sets itself as default for him too...

Is there a way to make sure only keyboards defined on server works and not those pushed thru RDP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To completly ignore the remote keyboard layout, use the registry key as listed in http://support.microsoft.com/?id=322042.  Although the KB lists windows 2000, the key works just as well for 2008.

Once applied, the local keyboard layout on a client machine connecting to a server with that registry key will be ignored, and the default keyboard layout for the remote machine as set up in control panel will be used instead.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be it (haven't tried but it sure looks like it).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem all the time.
You have to change the registry on the RDS server.

To do so, please perform the following steps:

1. On the terminal server, click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout

3. On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry information:

Value name: IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout
Data type: REG_DWORD
Value data: 1

4. Quit Registry Editor.

Answer (score 0):

I would login to the server, go to the Control Panel > Category View, 'Change keyboards or other input methods' and uninstall the PL license from the OS. If you don't actually need to use it, it shouldn't be a problem to uninstall it, right?

I have no way to test this, so I may be off base.

Comment: THere's no PL license on that german server..

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this using the quick-switch keys to change the input language. By default this is LEFT ALT + SHIFT.

Comment: I know about this and i use it frequently. The problem is with my customer who doesn't want to switch every time .. He is at his own backyard and shouldn't need to switch anything.

Answer (score 0):

As for Windows Server 2008 R2, I also had to take below steps to make the on-screen keyboard disappear after a RDP connection:

*Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Ease of Access Center->
**Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard***

Make sure "**Use On-Screen Keyboard**" checkbox is **disabled**. HTH.